# Can’t install Windows 7 after CPU upgrade

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have been running Windows 7 since release (almost) on an Intel Core 2 Duo E6600 no problem.  I recently upgraded to a Core 2 Quad 8300.  When I tried to boot, Windows did not start and displayed a screen that said the installation was corrupt and could have been caused by a recent hardware change.  So since it had been while anyway, I did a format and reinstall.  Since doing this, I am unable to get Windows 7 to run on my machine.

It installs OK, but on the first time startup, I get a blank screen after the "Starting Windows..." display.  My monitor then goes into stand-by (indicating no video signal).  This has happened every time after multiple retried installs.  If I try and boot in safe-mode, it tells me I cannot run first time setup in safe mode and just restarts.

The strange thing is, I can install my version of Windows Vista that I got with the computer originally just fine.  That boots and works all well and good. I think that it is the hardware change that is the problem, but I have no idea why that would be or what I can do about it.

Comment: Are you installing W7 while in Vista? or are you booting from the W7 DVD and doing a clean install?

Answer (score 2):

If Vista runs fine on your system, there is no reason that 7 will not.
There is a chance that some of the install files are damaged.

Try to install 7 (with the same CD) on other system if you can, just to make sure that his not the culprit (which I think he is)